# How to read a file in a TTask? (Delphi, fmx)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to read bitmap files and then copy them in an image component. I would like to do this in a TTask to keep the GUI responsive.  If I run the minimized code below, then sometimes the apple image appears correctly and sometimes it appears without content (a grey square).  If I put the bmp.LoadFromFile(..) in the TThread.Synchronize, then it seems to works fine, but is it necessary to put it in the TThread.Synchronize?

I do not understand why it does not work as is, because 1) if I look at the source code of LoadFromFile then the procedure starts with TMonitor.Enter(Self); and 2) when I save the bmp twice as commented out in the code, then the first save always contains the correct image (so the LoadFromFile seems to work), but the second save sometimes gives the correct image and sometimes a black image (but with the correct size)?

I am new to threading, so am hoping that someone can shed some light on this and what the correct way is to read images in a TTask.  I am using Delphi 10.3.3.

Thanks,
Gerard

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTask.Run(procedure
    var bmp: TBitmap;
    begin
      bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      bmp.LoadFromFile('apple.bmp');
      //  bmp.SaveToFile('apple1.bmp');
      //  bmp.SaveToFile('apple2.bmp');

      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Form1.Image1.bitmap.CopyFromBitmap(bmp, Rect(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 100, 100 );
        end);

      bmp.Free;
    end);
 end;
```

Comment: Not sure why you would be multi threading a file operation. It's not going to make anything faster and it will make your code more tricky. Is there another reason.

Comment: It would be multiple files, but you are right that it indeed might not affect the GUI responsiveness much.  Still I am wondering why the above behaves like it does.

Comment: On which platform you are running this code? I have mixed up two questions, and assumed you are running on Android, where this operation (and your code) should be thread safe.

Comment: In the end it should be for Android and iOS, but was running this on Windows.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on Windows, nor Android. There are some parts on Windows that are not fully thread safe, but only if `IWICImagingFactory` is not yet initialized which it is once application main form is visible. What does not work is your exact code even if I run it in main thread, because `CopyFromBitmap` needs `Image.Bitmap` width and height initialized. Adding initialization or using simple assignment `Image1.Bitmap := Bmp;` works properly. I also used absolute paths for location image instead of relative, but that could only have effect if you are changing current folder.

Comment: Sorry about not being complete.  I can reproduce the issue by putting a TImage and a TButton on a form, adding system.threading in the uses, put on image in the bitmap of the TImage (e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Original-standard-test-image-of-Peppers-Figure-14-Original-standard-test-image-of_fig15_259521525) and add an image (apple.bmp) in the same folder as the exe of the program (for example the same image from the link minified).  I now discovered that to see the anomaly relatively often, the 'apple.bmp' image needs to be fairly small (e.g. 32x24 pixels).

Comment: PS Still reading your great book on threading, thanks for writing it.

Comment: Thanks! I still cannot reproduce the issue, even with small bitmap and using TImage with preloaded content. `TMonitor.Enter` you mentioned is not guarantee that whole process is thread safe. It only means that you can share that same bitmap variable between multiple threads and try simultaneously load the content. However, TBitmap class has some parts that don't look thread-safe, so it is quite possible that sharing bitmap between threads would not work as expected. But that does not apply to your example, because you don't have simultaneous access from two threads.

Comment: Loading bitmap in one thread and assigning it to TImage in main thread should be thread safe. Still, there is a lot of code in behind that does the loading and every single bit needs to be thread-safe and as far as I can tell it is (except for the initialization part, but again that is not relevant once the form is visible) But, bugs are certainly possible and issues in multithreading are not always easily reproducible.

Comment: Have you tried how it behaves on Android. Manipulating images uses native platform APIs that behave differently - and if there are bugs on one platform, others may work without issues.

Comment: I found out why it fails on Windows. If you are using D2D canvas, it is not thread safe because it uses TMessageManager.DefaultManager that can only be used in the context of the main thread. Same goes for DX9 canvas. It is possible that using other canvases is thread safe, but I would not bet on it...

Comment: Thanks Dalija and others.  On Android it indeed seems to work.